# How can execute a cron at machine sturtup?

Tags: cron

I am trying to make a `cron` for my machine. It there a possibility to make it for every starting up of my pc?

Some way like this :

```
# File : /tmp/crontab.LgVuXf/crontab

uptime ... command
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run scripts on start up?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/814/how-to-run-scripts-on-start-up)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As specified in `man 5 crontab`, which contains the format of crontab files:

> Instead of the first five fields, one  of  eight  special  strings 
>   may
>          appear:
>
> ```
>           string         meaning
>           ------         -------
>           @reboot        Run once, at startup.
>           @yearly        Run once a year, "0 0 1 1 *".
>           @annually      (same as @yearly)
>           @monthly       Run once a month, "0 0 1 * *".
>           @weekly        Run once a week, "0 0 * * 0".
>           @daily         Run once a day, "0 0 * * *".
>           @midnight      (same as @daily)
>           @hourly        Run once an hour, "0 * * * *".
> ```

So you should be able to add a crontab line in the form

```
@reboot  bash /full/path/to/the/script
```

You can use the command `crontab -e` to edit the file, or input directly --- look at `man crontab` for details.